# Transform grammar for repeating characters into LL(1)

Tags: formal-languages, left-recursion

I have the following simple production rule:

S -> Sa | a

Which is left-recursive, and can recognize strings such as a or aa, etc

I tried to make it right-recursive, but I cannot find a way without creating ambigious grammars
(e.g.
 S -> aS'
S' -> a | aS'
)

Can someone explain how to make this grammar right-recursive and LL(1) form?

Comment: The grammars you have provided are not equivalent (the 2nd one doesn't generate the string "a").

Comment: I only meant to provide the first production rule as part of the question. I.e., how do you rewrite "S -> Sa | a" to valid LL(1) form?

Comment: Also, the 2nd grammar is [not ambiguous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ambiguous_grammar#Unary_string).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's construct an LL(1) grammar for the language $\mathscr{L}(a^+)$.

Firstly, observe that all the production rules in this case must have one of two forms:
$$A \to a\Gamma$$
or
$$A \to \epsilon,$$
where $\Gamma$ is a (possibly empty) sequence of non-terminals and the terminal 'a'.

The first step would be adding the rule $S \to aS'$, since it's clear that $S \to aS \mid a$ doesn't give us an LL(1) grammar.
Obviously $S'$ must have a production rule with the empty string as its body $S' \to \epsilon$, which will be used when we get the end of string symbol $\$$ during parsing. We also need a "looping construct" to finish our construction, resulting in the following LL(1) grammar:

$$\begin{align}
S  &\to aS' \\
S' &\to \epsilon \mid aS'
\end{align}$$

[From wikipedia:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Left_recursion)

> A nonterminal is left-recursive if the leftmost symbol in one of its productions is itself (...) or can be made itself by some sequence of substitutions (...).

Since neither $S'$ nor $S$'s left-most non-terminal symbol cannot be 'made itself' by any sequence of substitutions (there are simply no left-most non-terminal symbols there), the resulting grammar is not left-recursive.

Answer (score 0):

you can change your grammar in this way using epsilon symbol :

1. S -> aS'
2. S' -> e
3. S' -> aS'

if you want to realize LL1 grammars , you can first read the example of simple Mathematical Grammar :

1. E -> E + E
2. E -> E * E
3. E -> id
4. E -> (E)

this grammar is ambiguous and left recursive too , so we can change it in this way :

1. E -> TE'
2. E' -> +TE'
3. E' -> e
4. T -> FT'
5. T' -> *FT'
6. T' -> e
7. F -> id
8. F -> (E)

if you learn this so good you'll learn LL1 grammar